# i want to get the image link in firestore

Tags: flutter, dart

i want to get the image link in database, but i get the image url in other document and (name & etc) in other document.

```
database.collection("car").add({
                                        "item Name": nameText.text,
                                        "item Price": priceText.text,
                                        "seller Number": cellNoText.text,
                                        "seller add": addText.text,
                                        "image 1 Url": await uploadPic()
                                            .then((value) async {
                                          DocumentReference docRef = Firestore
                                              .instance
                                              .collection("car")
                                              .document();
                                          await docRef.setData(
                                              {"image 1 Url": value},
                                              merge: true);
                                        }),

                                        
                                      });
```

this is the function to upload the image to firebase storage

```
 uploadPic() async {
    String fileName = path.basename(_image1.path);
    StorageReference reference = storage.ref().child(fileName);
    StorageUploadTask uploadTask = reference.putFile(_image1);
    StorageTaskSnapshot taskSnapshot = await uploadTask.onComplete;
    String url = await taskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
    imageUrl1 = url;
    return url;
  }
```

can you guys help?

Comment: Can you write me the code @LOfG

Comment: Sorry, i misunderstood your question, i have added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your image url has been created in the wrong location because of the then of the **uploadPic()**, and its null in the car document because you need to call the Future function before adding it to the document:

```
Future uploadPic() async {
  String fileName = path.basename(_image1.path);
  StorageReference reference = storage.ref().child(fileName);
  StorageUploadTask uploadTask = reference.putFile(_image1);
  StorageTaskSnapshot taskSnapshot = await uploadTask.onComplete;
  String url = await taskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();

  return url;
}

Future saveData() async {
  String imageUrl = await uploadPic();  //calling and adding the result to a variable before adding

  database.collection("car").add({
    "item Name": nameText.text,
    "item Price": priceText.text,
    "seller Number": cellNoText.text,
    "seller add": addText.text,
    "imageUrl": imageUrl,
  });
}
```